# What does this statement in Group By do? Is it really necessary?

Tags: sql, sql-server, select

What does `FirstName+' '+LastName` do in the following Group By statement, is it really necessary? I tried omitting it, and it produced the same result.

```
SELECT FirstName+' '+LastName AS Employee, tblEmployee.EID, SUM(GrossAmount) AS [2011 Gross], SUM(NetAmount) AS [2011 Net], SUM(GrossAmount) - SUM(NetAmount) AS [2011 Taxes & WH]
FROM tblEmployee INNER JOIN tblPaycheck ON tblEmployee.EID=tblPaycheck.EID
WHERE YEAR(PayDate)=2011
GROUP BY tblEmployee.EID, LastName, FirstName, FirstName+' '+LastName
HAVING SUM(NetAmount)>=45000
ORDER BY LastName, FirstName, tblEmployeeA7.EID
```

Comment: It concatenates the first and last name into a single column. If you omit it in the select, then you have to omit it in the `GROUP BY`.  Since you are grouping by the full name, then you do not need the group by separate `lastname` and `firstname`

Comment: Since the result set is ordered by `LastName, FirstName...`, those columns do need to be included in the `group by`. Testing (SQL 2008) implies that only those two are needed, even when they are concatenated into one column in the `select` clause (i.e. the concatentation does not need to be included in the `group by`.)

Comment: @bluefeet sorry, I meant to ask what does 'FirstName+' '+LastName' in the 'GROUP BY' statement, not the SELECT, sorry for the confusion

Answer (score 2):

It would produce the same result, since the last name and first name are present, this could also be said if you removed lastname and firstname instead of the firstname + ' ' + lastname. Either way you get the same results

Group by takes columns by precedence.

Comment: sorry, I meant to ask what does 'FirstName+' '+LastName' in the 'GROUP BY' statement, not the SELECT, sorry for the confusion. And we cannot remove LastName, FirstName because if we do, out Order By would produce an error